# Multiplying Form Template with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form template :

```
<form>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <div id="template">
    <input type="text" name="info[name][]" />
    <input type="text" name="info[address][]" />
    <input type="text" name="info[gender][]" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I want when the select tag's value is change (ex : from 1 into 2), the div with id TEMPLATE multiply into 2, Become like this.

```
<form>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <div id="template">
    <input type="text" name="info[name][]" />
    <input type="text" name="info[address][]" />
    <input type="text" name="info[gender][]" />
  </div>
  <div id="template">
    <input type="text" name="info[name][]" />
    <input type="text" name="info[address][]" />
    <input type="text" name="info[gender][]" />
  </div>
</form>
```

The number of template have to match with the select value, if the select value is 1, then there will only 1 template div, if 3, then there will be 3 template div.

Anybody know how to do it with jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a change handler for the select with cloning like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $template = $('#template').addClass('template');
  $('select').change(function() {
    //required number of copies
    var count = +this.value;
    var $templates = $('.template');
    //if there are more number copies remove them
    if ($templates.length > count) {
      $templates.slice(count).remove();
    } else {
      //add new copies if required
      for (var i = $templates.length; i < count; i++) {
        var $clone = $template.clone().insertAfter($templates.last());
        $clone.find('input').val('');
      }

    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <div id="template">
    <input type="text" name="info[name][]" />
    <input type="text" name="info[address][]" />
    <input type="text" name="info[gender][]" />
  </div>
</form>
```